# How to pause the ffmpeg recording process?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on a screencasting application and using ffmpeg for these purposes. I am able to start recording by calling ffmpeg with this command :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Microphone" output.flv
```

and able to stop by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> in the console. I am using [Qt](http://www.qt-project.org) and stopping through QProcess like this:

```
 myProcess->write("q");
```

Now, I want for the users to be able to pause the recording process and resume after,I could not find the right command to do that in ffmpeg. I would appreciate it if somebody helped with this.

Comment: To continue a stopped process, that is resume use kill -SIGCONT PID

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about QT... I used windows VB.net with multithreading suspense and resume the transcoding process.

I make use a thread calling ffmpeg as process, by few other threads called to suspend or resume the ffmpeg process.

Hope this info give you a direction.

Comment: I wonder if you got downvoted for suggesting a coding solution or for using VB.NET.